# Core URL Rewrite 1.9 Problem

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

I am trying to get a hold on our Core_URL_Rewrite table in our database. After truncating 3 months ago, we once again have 1.4million entries from 15000SKUs across 4 storeviews. The issue is so severe we are no longer able to reindex.

- Currently our URLs look like this:
  http://example.com/new-hi-vis-hat-12355 and change after every
  reindex, making it harder to get any kind of ranking on Google.
- We currently run on Magento 1.9.2.4 and have found that the EE SUPEE-389_EE_1.12.0.2_v1.patch is recommended for 1.7 and 1.8 but our developer doubts this will fix on our version.

We are willing to TRUNCATE and start again if we would be able to find a more permanent fix. Any advice at this stage would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue before, and apparently it is a bug with url_rewrites and indexing, that has to do with having numerical values at the end of your url_keys.
There is a good/lengthy explanation of the problem and possible solution offered here [Magento Url Rewrites](http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/magento-url-rewrites/), and an actual code sollution offered here [Fix Url Key Rewrites](https://www.atwix.com/magento/duplicated-product-url-keys-in-community-edition/)